# adding options to dropdownlist using jquery

Tags: jquery

Im new to jquery, and what im trying to do is add new option to a dropdownlist. Here what I have so far. Could somone explain what im doing wrong?

```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="drop_company" runat="server"/>

     These dont work:
    $("#drop_company").append($("<option>").val("this"));
    or
    $("#drop_company").append($("<option value="1">Apple</option>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

`$("#drop_company").append('<option value="1">Apple</option>');`

1. You were missing `$` in `("#drop_company")`
2. You can append it a simple string
3. You cannot use double quotes inside double quotes without escaping it, else you can use a single quote and inside which you can use double quotes like above.

Comment: the try above: $("#drop_company").append('<option value="1">Apple</option>'); Im not getting any scripting error